# How to add data fetched from a API to an HTML DataTable?

Tags: javascript, datatable

I'm trying to complete a DataTable with information gathered from an API.

I made a "fiddle" here to make it easier to help and understand what I mean: 
http://live.datatables.net/jujofoye/3/edit

I'm starting from an HTML table containing only ID's. Then I use that ID in a rowCallback to call an API and write the fetched value in the table with jQuery `$('td:eq(1)', nRow).html( json.Title );`

```
function customFnRowCallback( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
  var imdbID = aData[0];

  fetch("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i="+imdbID+"&plot=short&r=json&tomatoes=true")
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html( json.Title );
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
  });
}
```

However the problem here is that you cannot sort on the second column. Even though you can see the data perfectly fine. I bet the DataTable doesn't really know there is new data and you end up sorting empty values instead of the values you added.

A second effect of this same issue (which does not show in my fiddle) is that collapsed rows (rows should collapse when not enough width) also show up empty when the row is expanded.
A third effect is that the search doesn't work on fetched data.

Is there a way to really add the fetched data to the DataTable? Not cosmetically that is.

(Note: All the responses I can find are about populating a full DataTable with an AJAX request. I'm only adding data to an already populated DataTable)

Comment: Any particular reason why you do not get the data first then build the table as suggested by  Peter Chon or use the ajax that is part of the DataTable api?

Comment: @Bindrid Yes there is, the rowCallback only runs for visible data. So even if you have a million records the api calls are limited as you can see here the api only runs 10x: http://live.datatables.net/jujofoye/11/edit

Comment: @Bindrid another reason is that I don't know when the api responses will be returned before I can build the datable, it might take a lot of unpredictable time

Comment: What is the original source of the of the ids in the first column?  If you set the serverSide to true, you can use the data:function(parm){} to grab the ids for the current page and get all the data for the visible ids at once.

Comment: @Bindrid The initial data comes from a basic node server and is injected with ejs (embedded js) in html table. I'm afraid I don't get what you propose, do you have examples?

Comment: I have some ideas to try but I am at the start of my work day so I am not sure how much attention I can give this before tonight.

Comment: Before I pursue my ideas, is the server under your control? Can you, for example, send a json array to the server and get back more than one row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136475/discussion-between-stalling-one-and-bindrid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a different approach.   I used the DataTable ajax with when/done so it will not refresh the table until all the gets are processed.

I set sorting so the list will come out alphabetically even those that is not the order of the list.
I also got unique set of values from  imdb.

http://jsbin.com/yojoka/edit?html,js,output

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Sample return set  from 
    var sampleReturn = { "Title": "Seven Samurai", "Year": "1954", "Rated": "UNRATED", "Released": "19 Nov 1956", "Runtime": "207 min", "Genre": "Adventure, Drama", "Director": "Akira Kurosawa", "Writer": "Akira Kurosawa (screenplay), Shinobu Hashimoto (screenplay), Hideo Oguni (screenplay)", "Actors": "Toshirô Mifune, Takashi Shimura, Keiko Tsushima, Yukiko Shimazaki", "Plot": "A poor village under attack by bandits recruits seven unemployed samurai to help them defend themselves.", "Language": "Japanese", "Country": "Japan", "Awards": "Nominated for 2 Oscars. Another 5 wins & 6 nominations.", "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTc5MDY1MjU5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDM2OTE4MzE@._V1_SX300.jpg", "Metascore": "98", "imdbRating": "8.7", "imdbVotes": "238,165", "imdbID": "tt0047478", "Type": "movie", "Response": "True" };
    var deferreds = [];
    var newData = [];
    $(function ($) {
        var dt = $("#example").DataTable({
            columnDefs:[{targets:[0, -1], width:"150px"}],
            columns: [
                { data: "imdbID" },
                { data: "Title" },
                { "data": "Year" }
            ],
            deferLoading: 0,
            deferRendering: true,
            "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
            ajax: function (data, cb, setting) {
                // get the list of ids created by DataTables from the embedded html
                var curData = $("#example").DataTable().rows().data();
                // if you don't clear, you will end up with double entries
                $("#example").DataTable().clear();
                $.each(curData, function (i, item) { 
                    var sr = { i: item.imdbID, plot:"short", r:"json", "tomatoes":true};
                    deferreds.push(
                    $.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/", sr)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        // push the response into the global array
                        newData[newData.length] = response;
                    })
                );
                });

                // now make all of the calls. When done, use the callback to return the data and populate the table
                $.when.apply(null, deferreds)
                   .done(function () {
                       cb({ data: newData })
                 });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! (I lost lazy loading however, I'll need to find something for that.)

Comment: If you want to be able to sort on columns across all of the columns you are going to give up lazy loading anyway.  If you are willing to give up search and sort features, you can bring in the data page at a time.  Unfortunately, your options are limited because you are working with omdbapi's interface and their options are fairly limited.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in that DataTable doesn't know what's in the table to sort.
I would say to run the function once the table is completely made.

```
$('#example').find('tbody tr').each(customFnRowCallback);

function customFnRowCallback()
{
  var $this = $(this);
  var imdbID = $this.find('td:eq(0)').text();

  fetch("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i="+imdbID+"&plot=short&r=json&tomatoes=true")
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    $this.find('td:eq(1)').text( json.Title );
  })
  .then(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
  });
}
```

Comment: This is working, but has 2 problems:  1) if I have a million rows it will make a million api calls. Do you know how to do that only for visible rows?   2) How do I know when all api calls are finished to run the datatable?

Comment: Well, based on your original code you are making a call for every ID. So I don't know what to say about that.

Normally, we would make the call then create the entire table based on the returned object.

The problem with your situation is that you're dynamically appending the data, so .DataTable() doesn't know what to sort.